# python pandas change order and column name after merge

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have merged two dataframes with multiple overlapping columns. I would like to put the columns side by side.

```
merge = df1.merge(df2)
```

For example, Current Output:

```
YEAR_x,DATE_x,MAX_x,MIN_x,YEAR_y,DATE_y,MAX_y,MIN_y
```

I want the output to be:

```
YEAR, YEAR_auto, DATE, DATE_auto, MAX, MAX_auto, MIN, MIN_auto
```

I have more than 150 columns so I don't want to do it manually. How could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pd.merge` with `suffixes` parameter:

```
merge = df1.merge(df2[set(df2) & set(df1)], suffixes=('', '_auto'))
```

To sort your columns as df1:

```
cols = sorted(merge.columns, key=lambda x: df1.columns.get_loc(x.split('_')[0]))
```

Example:

```
>>> merge
   YEAR        DATE  MAX  MIN  YEAR_auto   DATE_auto  MAX_auto  MIN_auto
0  2021  2021-08-06  100    0       2020  2020-08-06        50        20

>>> merge[cols]
   YEAR  YEAR_auto        DATE   DATE_auto  MAX  MAX_auto  MIN  MIN_auto
0  2021       2020  2021-08-06  2020-08-06  100        50    0        20
```

Comment: Does the "out" refer to the merged dataframe? I got "KeyError: 'SENSOR 1 OFFSET'" when sorting the columns. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, my bad. I usually call my output dataframe `out`. I fixed it.

Comment: I suppose `SENSOR 1 OFFSET` only exists in `df2`, that's right? Your code shows only pairwise columns. What do you want to do with columns that exist only in one of dataframes?

Comment: Yes, and I would like to get rid of these columns that don't exist in df1

Comment: When you merge, select only df2 columns present in df1: `df2[set(df2) & set(df1)]`